# Check WiFi logs on macOS Ventura 13

Tags: macos, wifi, logs

I enabled WiFi logging by pressing <kbd>Option ^</kbd> + WiFi icon in menu bar, and then went to check `/var/log/wifi.log`. The problem is that this file doesn't seem to record what I want, so I'm wondering if there's some other file I should be checking. Here's the last couple lines of the file :

```
Fri May 19 11:01:49.028 Usb Host Notification Error Apple80211Set: Device power is off seqNum 13023 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:01:49.418 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13024 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:01:49.431 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13025 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:18:34.036 Usb Host Notification Error Apple80211Set: Device power is off seqNum 13026 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:18:34.480 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13027 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:18:34.496 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13028 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:34:10.030 Usb Host Notification Error Apple80211Set: Device power is off seqNum 13029 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:34:10.487 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13030 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:34:10.507 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13031 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:51:43.039 Usb Host Notification Error Apple80211Set: Device power is off seqNum 13032 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:51:43.503 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13033 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:51:43.518 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13034 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:54:59.346 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13035 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:54:59.471 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13036 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:54:59.489 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13037 Total 0 chg 0 en0
Fri May 19 11:54:59.660 Usb Host Notification Apple80211Set: seqNum 13038 Total 0 chg 0 en0
```

Right now it's around 4PM, but the logs stop at around noon (and they start at around midnight), and I'm not getting what process is using the WiFi, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348574/442100) to try and find the problem that is causing my latency spikes, and is making parsec stutters when I'm using it (that's irrelevant here, I'm just adding that for keyword information for anyone that might have some issues like me related to parsec). I'm also running `ping` in parallel, to pinpoint the time where the latency spikes happen.

I also tried solving this issue I had a couple months ago, and at the time I also got stuck at checking the logs. Back then the log file had only 1 or 2 lines (iirc) which were something like
"(something about my pc name and date) `newsyslog[75627]: logfile turned over`". At the time I didn't have WiFi logging enabled, so I had just enabled it. And so I gave up. Finally today I wanted to get back at this issue. WiFi logging has been active since then. So now I'm getting something more than 1 or 2 lines, but it's still now what I'm looking for.