# MacOS /var/log/wifi.log contains no info. Unable to initialize unified logger

Tags: macos, network, wifi, logs

I'm experiencing ping spikes on my MacBook Pro M2, Sonoma MacOS. Tried to get some logs as being told here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348574. However, no matter what, no logs appear in wifi.log file. I mostly get next messages there:

```
Sat Mar 30 11:34:59.456 <airport[417]> _initInterface: Unable to initialize unified logger
Sat Mar 30 11:34:59.457 <airport[417]> _initInterface: Unable to initialize unified temp logger
Sat Mar 30 11:34:59.457 <airport[417]> _initInterface: Unable to initialize logger
Sat Mar 30 11:34:59.457 <airport[417]> _initInterface: Unable to initialize driver message tracer monitor
Sat Mar 30 11:34:59.457 <airport[417]> _initInterface: Unable to initialize unified temporary logger
```

Is there any way to fix it and get similar logs to the link?